# Is this a form of insurance fraud? Provider charged us less than reported to insurance

Tags: fraud, medical-bill

We needed an expensive genetic test for our daughter. UCSF hospital suggested a new lower cost provider, and sent the sample in. The provider called us and said they are "unique" in that they would bill insurance a different amount than we actually would be held to.

Indeed.  We paid them $600.  They billed insurance $910, $2549, and $1184 all of which were paid at a $0 rate since we're on a high deductible plan. As it sits we're out only $600, but our yearly deductible is nearly met according to UHC our insurance company.

Something seems fishy about this.  I tried alerting UHC the insurance company, but I don't think they understood.  Is this a form of fraud?  If so who's making the money?

---

Note: After the sample went in, the test provider immediately called with a series of high pressure sales people, telling us the price would be $2000, or we could apply for "special pricing", by submitting income data.  They said "even if you make a million dollars" we'd be approved.  It sounded really sleazy.  We sent the data, and they dropped the price to $600.

They resisted putting this price in writing, but after several calls, eventually relented.

I won't name them in public, as I don't want to advertise their services even indirectly.  If you're considering a cut rate genetic test however, you'll probably encounter them.

Comment: It may depend on whether the lab was in-network or out-of-network. If in-network, a provider usually has agreed to certain amounts and can't bill the patient anything over what the insurance pays.

Answer (score 7):

Most states have an insurance regulator with a hotline you can call if you suspect insurance fraud to talk with someone about whether your situation might constitute fraud.

Since you mentioned UCSF I am assuming you are in California. I'm sure they would be happy to answer questions like this regardless of whether you want to file a complaint.

[California Department of Insurance Fraud division](https://www.insurance.ca.gov/0300-fraud/0100-fraud-division-overview/)

Here is their guidance about what constitutes fraud:

> Fraud occurs when **someone knowingly lies to obtain a benefit or
> advantage to which they are not otherwise entitled** or someone
> knowingly denies a benefit that is due and to which someone is
> entitled. According to the law, the crime of insurance fraud can be
> prosecuted when:
>
> - The suspect had the intent to defraud. Insurance
>   fraud is a "specific" intent crime. This means a prosecutor must prove
>   that the person involved knowingly committed an act to defraud.
> - An act
>   is completed. Simply making a misrepresentation (written or oral) to
>   an insurer with knowledge that is untrue is sufficient. The act and
>   intent must come together. One without the other is not a crime.
> - Actual loss is not needed as long as the suspect has committed an act
>   and had the intent to commit the crime. No money necessarily has to be
>   lost by a victim.

You might be careful though. If you were complicit in this scheme you might technically be considered as a perp and not a victim in this scenario.